# create DateTime string for the beginning and the end of the day

Tags: php

If I have a string of the following:

```
"2013-10-28"
```

and when I convert to a `DateTime` using the following function:

```
new \DateTime("2013-10-28");
```

it always gives me a `DateTime` with the time not set.

I want to have two **DateTime :**

- one marking the beginning of the day, meaning at **00:00:00**
- another `DateTime` which is on the same date but at the end of the day **23:59:59**.

How do I do this given the string above?

Comment: You could simply _append_ `00:00:00` / `23:59:59` to the date, and then use those values to create your DateTime objects …?

Comment: `new DateTime("2013-10-28");` works for me, time is set.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at all possible [compound formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php).

The MySQL format should be the easiest for your use case:

```
new \DateTime("2013-10-28 00:00:00");
new \DateTime("2013-10-28 23:59:59");
```

Answer (score 45):

Use [DateTime::setTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php)

```
$d = new \DateTime("2013-10-28");
$d->setTime(23, 59, 59);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public static Date getDayStartTimeOfTheDate(Date date){
        try {
          Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         c.setTime(date);
         c.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 0);
         c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
         c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
         c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
         c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        return parseDate(format(c.getTime()));
      } catch (ParseException e) {

    }
}
```

And for end time you can write method base on above logic.

Comment: Oops i gave java approach. Let it be it will also be fine for Java users

Comment: Too bad Java users will have a slim to none chance of even stumbling across this answer, since nothing in the question or tags point to anything Java.

Comment: Haha i cant remove this answer too against stackoverflow :(